# How to customize registration page for silverlight business application?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight-4.0, .net-4.0

When you create a silverlight 4 business application, using VS2010, by default you will get a login and registration page.  I need to customize the registration page, to add more fields.  How do I do that?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web project generated has a class called `BusinessApplication.Web.RegistrationData`, which you can modify to include more fields. This same class is then generated on the client side for the Silverlight App, and the DataForm control used on the RegistrationForm will automatically detect the fields in the `RegistrationData` class.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I will try that to see if I can do what I am trying to do.

Comment: I can not find the class BusinessApplication.Web.RegistrationData in the solution.  I only see a resource file "RegistrationDataResources.resx".  I tried adding a new field to this file, but nothing happens on the UI.  Any ideas?

Comment: I created a new "Silverlight Business Application" project in VS2010. In the BusinessApplication.Web project, expand Models, and you should see the RegistrationData.cs file. This file has the RegistrationData class. There you can add/modify/delete properties which will then show up on the Registration Form.